# Is Javascript inlining possible in Freemarker template engine?

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf, freemarker

Is it possible to perform Javascript inlining for complex objects in Freemarker template engine to achieve what can be done in Thymeleaf? For example, as described in [Thymeleaf tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart), if we had the following code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var user = [[${session.user}]];
</script>
```

The `${session.user}` expression will evaluate to a User object, and Thymeleaf will correctly convert it to Javascript syntax:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var user = {'age':null,'firstName':'John','lastName':'Apricot',
                'name':'John Apricot','nationality':'Antarctica'};
</script>
```

If there a similar feature in Freemarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything specialized for that purpose. You can do this if you want to print a simple string:

```
<script>
  var user = "${session.user?js_string}";
</script>
```

and similarly `var someNumber = ${session.someNumber?c};` for a number. But there's no built-in solution for dumping composite objects.

I was wondering if adding `?json` to FreeMarjer, which converts an arbitrary object to JSON (also valid JavaScript), would be a good idea (it's very often needed), but the security implications are scary. You dump the content of an object recursively to the client... When developers add getters to a class, they don't necessary realize that the template will traverse an expose the whole object graph through that.

But, you can add a method to the data-model or as shared variable to the `Configuration` singleton that does that. `var something = ${toJS(session.something)};`. (Or actually, a `#macro` can do this as well, but it's uglier and somewhat slower.) But consider how will you keep in hand what's exposed to the client.